# Computer freezes before BIOS

Tags: windows, boot, motherboard, bios, freeze

I just tried booting my computer, and it seems to freeze prior to getting to BIOS. It gets stuck on the below screen (pic taken from phone), and F2 / DEL do not work to get me to BIOS settings. I shut it down this morning as I always do, by just clicking start > Power > Shutdown. Specs listed below.

- Motherboard: Asus ROG Maximus X Hero
- Processor: i7-8700k (not
  overclocked)
- Memory: 32gb DDR4 2666 GPU:
- Gigabyte 1080ti
- PSU:
  Rosewill 850w Gold
- OS: Windows 10 Home

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Edit: an update - the mobo switches between error code A2 and Ad. A2 is IDE detect error, so I unplugged all of the SSDs on the PC, and then I get code Ad. I tried plugging each ssd in individually and have had no success still.

Comment: What's the motherboard vendor error code list say for those two error codes for that specific motherboard?

Comment: A2 - IDE Detect.        Ad - Ready to boot event

Comment: I suggest making an Ubuntu LiveCD or equivalent USB stick on another PC.  Put it into your optical drive or USB2 port (some motherboards can't boot from USB3) and attempt to boot from it.  If it can't start from that, you're likely having hardware issues and should call the vendor.  I'm not certain from the initial description if this is the first time you've booted this PC - if you recently bought the part, you may still be under warranty.

Comment: Sorry for not putting that info. I relatively recently upgraded the PC, about a month ago.  It has been running flawlessly until last night, and I still have no idea what the issue could be, but with all 3 SSDs disconnected, it still wont let me get to bios. I'll try the ubuntu live CD, appreciate the suggestion. But if bios isnt set up to boot with that in a higher priority, would it it not boot from USB until I went into bios to set the priority to boot from USB?

Comment: The mobo can recognize whether SATA disks are connected or not.  Therefore, if you physically disconnect the SATA disks, and USB boot was already in the list down farther than SATA, and you have a known-working USB boot device plugged in, then it should attempt to boot from USB.  Or there is a hardware issue on the motherboard, and you need to call the vendor.  Some mobos have BIOS reset buttons, but I would suggest calling the vendor first.

Comment: Found the issue from moving the computer to my dining room, and taking everything apart and slowly putting it back together while booting with each part. Eventually all parts were in and it successfully booted. Oddly enough, the power strip was the issue in my office. I took the PC back to the office, used the old power strip, and it didn't boot. Used a new power strip and has booted every time. I'll be buying a UPS on Saturday to ensure a simple power strip won't affect my PC in any way. I appreciate all of your help as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my specific issue, it was a power strip failure. Replacing the power strip worked like a charm. See comments for more specifics.

Answer (score -1):

Your Bios is corrupted either by a virus or incomplete flash update. YOu can either reflash it with a USB drive or solder in a new BiOS chipset

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Utter nonsense if you look at how issue was resolved.